# jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin shows scrollbars even if they not needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, youtube, jquery-ui-dialog

I use the jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin from here:

http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

and in most of the Browsers it works but sometimes in some cases not. Then scrollbars are shown at the jquery dialog box even if they are not needed.

How can i deactivate them?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#id").css('overflow','hidden');
```

replace #id with your element

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a CSS rule for the div that gains the scrollbars:

```
overflow: hidden;
```